# DefaultPageSettings.Margins not adding margins

Tags: c#, wpf, margins, printdocument

Based from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.margins(v=vs.110).aspx), adding these codes should add margin to the print document, but when I used it in my codes, I can't see any margin being added. Is my usage on the code correct? Here is the code from MSDN:

```
 printFont = new Font("Arial", 10);
 PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument(); 
 pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
 pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printer;
 Margins margins = new Margins(100,100,100,100);
 pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = margins;
 pd.Print();
```

Here is my code:

```
printDoc = new PrintDocument();
PrinterSettings printSettings = new PrinterSettings();
PaperSize paperSize = new PaperSize("Receipt", 350, 700);

Margins margin = new Margins(2000, 1000, 2000, 1000);
printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;

printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pdoc_PrintPage);
PrintPreviewDialog printPreview = new PrintPreviewDialog();
printPreview.Document = printDoc;
DialogResult result = printPreview.ShowDialog();
printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = margin;
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    printDoc.Print();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why there are no margins affecting the document is because I didn't change the value of `OriginAtMargins` to true. So you need to change it from the `PrintDocument()`, like this:

```
New printDoc = new PrintDocument();
printDoc.OriginAtMargins = true; //Default is false
```